# How can I have a popup smoothly track a coordinate while the cesium globe is being rotated?

Tags: javascript, css, cesiumjs

I have a [sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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).

If I rotate the globe, the position of the popup will track the coordinate I have it attached to. However, the movement of the popup is choppy and lags behind the rotation. I would like the movement of the popup to be smooth, keeping up (within reason) with the speed of the rotation by the user.

How can this be accomplished?